# how to change actioncolumn heading and font color on index page in yii2

Tags: css, fonts, yii2, heading

that is my code for color changing in index

```
 [
  'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
  'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:100px;'],
  'header'=>'Actions',
 ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `headerOptions` property of ActionColumn Class

```
[
   'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:100px;'],
    'header'=>'Actions',
    'headerOptions' => [
         'style' => 'color:red'
     ] 
],
```

[ActionColumn ApiDoc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$headerOptions-detail)

Answer (score 1):

You just use `headerOptions` to set header color. show below code

Refer [Action Column](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$headerOptions-detail)

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'header' => 'Actions',
    'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'color:blue']
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your custom Css

```
.action-column{
color : red ;
}
```